# error compiling visual_feature_detectors packages -- opencv don't match

Tags: ros, vision-opencv, opencv2, cturtle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,I have installed cturtle using Ubuntu packages (Maverick 64), and have the package ros_cturtle_vision_opencv.
I'm trying to install visual_feature_detector from source: https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_cturtle/stacks/. When I try to compile i get errors like:

```
/ros/stacks/visual_feature_detectors/brief_descriptor/examples/video_homography.cpp:15: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No existe el fichero o el directorio
-------------------
cv.h:47: warning: #warning "This is a deprecated opencv header provided for compatibility. Please include a header from a corresponding opencv module"
-------------------
/visual_feature_detectors/features_2d_ros/include/features_2d_ros/any_detector.h:15: error: no matching function for call to ‘cv::FastFeatureDetector::FastFeatureDetector()’
```

I think that visual_feature_detector needs other opencv version, if this is correct, where can i found a version of visual_feature_detector that works with  ros_turtle_vision_opencv prebuild?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9129/error-compiling-visual_feature_detectors-packages----opencv-don%27t-match/) by [charias98](https://answers.ros.org/users/140/charias98/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2011-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Charias,

you are correct in your assumption: you have the wrong openCV installed.

The stack.xml file of visual_feature_detectors refers to the stack named vision_opencv.

```
<depend stack="vision_opencv" /> <!-- opencv2, image_geometry, cv_bridge -->
```

This stack contains the package opencv2.1 (as a lib) and some other packages built around it (like image_geometry, cv_bridge and opencv_tests).

Running the following command should install the correct version on your system:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-cturtle-vision-opencv
```

Hope this helps

Raph

---

Originally posted by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) with karma: 1382 on 2011-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1